# pgloader getting current datetime in bad format during migration data

Tags: postgresql, pgloader

I would like to ask, how to fix following error, where pgloader is getting a current datetime in bad format.

My load configuration is following:

```
LOAD DATABASE
    FROM mysql://root:xxxxxx@localhost:3326/originaldb
    INTO postgresql://postgres:xxxxx@localhost:15432/newdb

WITH data only, include no drop, truncate, disable triggers,
     create no indexes, drop indexes, reset sequences,
     batch rows = 1000, batch size = 500 MB, prefetch rows = 1000

ALTER SCHEMA 'originaldb' RENAME TO 'public'

ALTER TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~/.*/
    SET SCHEMA 'public'

SET timezone TO '+00:00'

SET PostgreSQL PARAMETERS
     maintenance_work_mem to '4096MB',
     work_mem to '2048MB';
```

During the migration process, I will get following error:

```
PROTOCOL-ERROR: PostgreSQL protocol error: Unexpected message received: Z 90
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   PostgreSQL protocol error: Unexpected message received: Z 90



2024-03-12T02:49:06.768132-04:00 ERROR Date/time: 2024-03-12-07:49!
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   PostgreSQL protocol error: Unexpected message received: Z 90
```

Thanks a lot for en each answer.

[image]

Comment: The  datetime looks correct: `select '2024-03-12T02:49:06.768132-04:00'::timestamptz; 2024-03-11 23:49:06.768132-07`. **Add answers to following as text update to question text**:  1) What is the data type of the field in the Postgres table this is being imported into? 2) What is shown in the Postgres log when this happens?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks a lot for your answer. Problem is, that from the log, I don't know, which table or which column is making this problem. But that date is not comming from source database, it's current time value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  ahh, I found the monkey mistake, I used incorrect command pgloader file.load --debug --verbose instead of correct pgloader --debug --verbose file.load. Now I have much more info from logs.